# Application as Service Win server 2003

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2003

I want to make a service from a .exe file.

To do this i can use software like FireDaemon or ExeToServices but i want to do it with sc.exe.
But I don't know how to do this, i have to add a paramater afther the specific .exe path

like: "C:\Program Files\Server1\example.exe" +set fs_game 1

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED, Firedaemon fixes my problem.